# How to display a line with fading transparency in qgis?

Tags: qgis, style, line, color, transparency-opacity

I have a straight line with two vertices, which I'd like to style. I want the style to be a fading line from start to end, so the transparency is gradually increasing from start to the end of the line. 
I thought I could make it with geometry generator, using some function to locate point along the line, then splitting the line into smaller parts and applying something like `color_hsva()` with `scale_exp()` to map the alpha to a distance. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any function to get a line substring or any analogue to the `st_line_locate_point()` postgis function.
Of course I can do this by splitting line in the data, adding a segment number to each part from startpoint, and then style them separately, but it's a bad solution. 
Any ideas how to do this by qgis styling and without messing with the data?

Comment: Seems like you will get this with QGIS 3 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/e110ba7d54b0ac7d3f63e8ed7eaebb2845f9f38c

Comment: And QGIS 2.18 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/a2d4bbe2b6ba7cb1c91b385fd033a23cdc7f1cd2

Comment: Great, didn't notice this in master. Really something like `st_line_substring()` should do the trick, would be nice to have that aswell.

Comment: See here for a similar question and the solutions offered there: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380806/visualize-a-polyline-with-decreasing-opacity-towards-its-ends-in-qgis/