# Visualizing polyline with decreasing opacity towards its ends in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, line, transparency-opacity, visualisation

For a mapping project I am looking for a method how to visualize a polyline where the ends increase in opacity such that it will look like its fades away using QGIS 3.10.10. See the red circle in the picture below.

In essence I am looking to style a polyline the way you would a DEM; with a color ramp that has 0% opacity at the lowest and highest values but instead of measures of height it would be of length. So, like a shape burst fill but for lines, I can imagine I have to play around with the geometry generator.

One solution would be to divide the polyline in several segments at fixed distances and give each segment an increased transparency, however I am looking for a less cumbersome and more robust method.

The result is purely for visual output e.g. the attribute table is not of importance.

[image: Red circle: polyline fade]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possibility is to apply `menu processing / toolbox / explode lines` and expode the line, i.e. to create a separate line from each line-segment. Now you can color each segment of the original line with a color ramp from transparent to color to transparent, using the id of the exploded lines (i.e. the segment-no. of the original line).

To do that, on the exploded line, change the color to a data driven styly, using the assistant:

[image]

In the assistant, set `$id` (meaning the id of the current feature) as the source, load min/max values (the number of lines/segments). You can change this values manually to adapt the style.

Than apply a color ramp and set the start and end marker to 100% transparency, clicking on the color ramp and changing the markers (you can delete an add markers and change their color):

[image]

This gives you the style of the blue line. The yellow line shows the original line with an offset to show the original shape of the line:

[image]

If you look close, where the lines/segments touch, they overlap and thus on the transparent parts, you have some darker dots. To remove these, simply change the end cap style from square to flat:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you babel also a very cool solution. In the end I marked this as the answer instead of @Erik's which is also a valid solution (!) based on the fact that this was more intuitive for me for visualization purposes with the color ramp etc.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [Geometry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) I was able to create the following:

[image]

The idea is to overlay transparent parts of the line over each other, with each substring a bit shorter than the one create before.

This is done by several layers of `line_substring($geometry, $length-$length*0.1, $length)`. `line_substring` creates a part of the handed `$geometry` based on starting and end points along the line. This exemplary line only goes from 90% of line length until the end. The next layer could start at 80% of line length, etc.

Depending on your background you might need to do a finer graduation that 10% of line length in order to create a smooth appearance.

Comment: Thank you Erik, after playing around a bit, this gave me the desired result, as well as a nice example of the geometry generator.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with QGIS 3.20 there is a new option to achieve this. You can use the [Interpolated line symbol layer type for vector layers](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-interpolated-line-symbol-layer-type-for-vector-layers) and set a color ramp like transparent/color/transparent.

*Screenshot: how to do the settings:*
[image]